# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_file'

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
driver = None


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome")
    parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default="staging")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    global driver
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    url = request.config.getoption("url")
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    if browser_name == 'chrome':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Softwares\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32_91version"
                                                  "\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Softwares\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
    elif browser_name == "IE":
        driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\Softwares\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe", options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    if url == 'staging':
        url = "URL"
    elif url == 'production':
        url = "URL"
    driver.get(url)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()


@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    """
        Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshot in html report, whenever test fails.
        :param item:
        """
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```

This is my conftest.py file. I initialized the driver globally and it will be defined under the setup fixture. I have custom reports code (it captures the screenshot, when the test fails). I am using the driver object to capture the screenshot, but I was not able to run the test because of this "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_file'"" error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: had you checked the variable driver when you are on the function?  I suppose you have variable problem (global vs local) , you can pass driver to function to avoid

Comment: It looks, you are not passing chrome driver path

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change your function capture screenshot to fixture and take your driver (setup fixture in your case) into that function like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _capture_screenshot(name, setup):
    yield
    setup.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```

You can also call capturing screenshot only when the test is finished using `yield` operator. Hope it helps a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my chorme driver version and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).